# Simplify this JS using the "#" tags

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I am extending code (associated with Telerik MVC) and came across a confusing section:

```
<img src="# if (sessionStorage.getItem(ImageId)) { # data:image/png;base64,#:sessionStorage.getItem(ImageId)# # } else { # @(Url.Content("~/Pictures/"))#:ImageId# # } #" />
```

I know what this is doing -- It retrieves an image from session state or assigns it to one from a /Pictures folder.

I need to extend this logic, but find it very confusing with the above structure. I am not familiar with it, and cannot find anything online to explain the "#" character that is in use. I also cannot find how to restructure it so it's more legible, especially if I extend, as right now everything is on one line. Any advice?

Comment: it appears that this is not JavaScript but some sort of macro that is being parsed.  the `#` are *probably* at the beginning of each line on the server code, before the newlines are stripped on the client side.

Comment: in fact, this is actually documented:  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview.  Particularly: > "3.  Execute arbitrary JavaScript code: `# if (true) { # ... non-script content here ... # } #`."